# Opposite of "failover"

Tags: software

Our software "knows" to migrate itself to spare hardware in case the main hardware is damaged. The process of such a migration is called **failover**.

When the main hardware is repaired the software can **migrate itself back to it.
How would you call such a process?**

We thought about "fail-back" (to stress it's a reverse of fail-over) and "fallback".

Thank you!

Comment: Failback seems to have some [acceptance](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/failback).

Comment: Hello, LiMar. 'Repatriation' is a metaphorical usage that springs to mind: pretty clear, if a little high-flown. But ELU's remit is to look at and try to explain **established** usages; suggested candidate words / usages do not fulfil the 'can be supported by research' requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The strict opposite of “failover” is “failback”.  Both can be hyphenated or not; just be consistent about it.

Note that failback means that B will switch back to A automatically when A is available again. If B remains active until *it* fails, then your system doesn’t have failback; it has double failover.